# Android: Order Headers Alphabetically in an Expandable List

Tags: android

I can't order alphabetically the headers of my Expandable List. I'm getting the headers of my list from my Database. I get the headers alphabetically order from Database but then when I add them to my Expandable List something happens, because when I test it(on my phone), they appear with no order. Can you please help?

```
    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    (...)
    List<String> categoria_header = new ArrayList<String>();
    Database db = new Database(context);
    List<Categorias> categorias;

    categorias = db.getAllCategorias();

    for (int i=0; i<categorias.size(); i++){

        //Log.d("Expandabe","-->"+categorias.get(i).toString());
        expandableListDetail.put(categorias.get(i).toString(), categoria_header);
    }
```

Then my getAllCategories method is:

```
public List<Categorias> getAllCategorias(){

        String selectQuery;
        Cursor cursor;
        int i=0;

        List<Categorias> categorias = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORIA + " ORDER BY " + col_NOME_CATEGORIA + " ASC;";
        //Log.d("Database-->",""+selectQuery);
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor !=null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Categorias categoria = new Categorias();

categoria.setNomeCategoria(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(col_NOME_CATEGORIA)));
                categorias.add(categoria);
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return categorias;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are putting the headers as keys into a `HashMap`, which does not maintain any sort of order of those keys. You might try using `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because your expandable list is `HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail`.

HashMaps are unordered i.e. the order in which you put the `K,V` pairs is not guaranteed to be the same when you are iterating over it.

In your scenario, you need a `LinkedHashMap` which will preserve the order of `K,V` pairs.

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)